# Have you tried printing an article?

Tags: feature-request

I routinely have to troubleshoot systems that are not connected to the internet.  That requires changing my monitor to the private network machine.  Even with a KVM switching back and forth is a problem.

The obvious solution would be to print the article so I can refer to it as I'm logged in to the system I'm working on.  Problem is the text of the article is barely 2 inches wide.  That's not only a waste of paper, it's essentially useless.

Can someone fix this?  The print out would be so much better if the main text was 5-6 inches wide.  The main text is the question and answers.

[image: Bad Print Example]

I am using Google Chrome 71, but the behavior is the same on multiple browsers.  Same issue in Firefox 60.5.

Comment: How are you attempting to print the page? Are you using your browser's native Print function, or something different? I'm on my phone right now so I don't know if the desktop layout is much different, but on chrome for Android, printing a question gave me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrHyT.png). (Note that's page 1 of 2, and it printed as a PDF and my lazy conversion to image for upload seems to have given it a black border that's not in the pdf, but the question itself is well spaced.)

Comment: Native print function.  Ctrl+P, and where I am imgur is blocked so I can't see your link.

Comment: Try posting an image of what it looks like to you. Specify which browser version you are using. Put in the question any other info that many help debug. Without those no one will be able to figure out why your print is failing while it works for everyone else. Also, why not just use the snipping tool (windows) or shutter (linux) to just capture the part of the screen with the question/answer if your print function is failing? That would seem to work as an alternate solution to the issue

Comment: Hopefully the paste worked, I personally cannot access imgur directly.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, paste worked fine. Issue is clearly visible in the image.

Comment: Even the top minds of [se] can't get CSS right...

Comment: I would ask why you can't get the setup modified to allow you to view the screens of a computer not connected to the outside world and one that is at the same time.

Comment: @JoeW, I'm OK if I'm at my desk, but not every environment is set up like that.  It's still a fundamental hole in SO functionality.  Sometimes I need to take it in to a server room without any internet capability at all.

Comment: Printing from web  browsers is in general completely broken. It is not just Stack Exchange. It may work better simply to take screenshots and print them out (hopefully there aren't too many pages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [open problem on the MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877/259412) since 2009.

There is no printer-friendly support on the site design. If it is really needed or useful, is another question - but we have http://www.stackprinter.com .

Comment: It might be great if I could get to it.  Stackprinter is closing the connection on me.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch You have probably some user-level network problem. It is pretty okay by me.

Comment: I have a restrictive firewall.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch the same happened for me and I have no restrictive firewall, it works for me when I go to the http site at `http://www.stackprinter.com/`. For now of course, maybe I'm simply exposing an oopsie and it was not intended that the http site was still accessible.

Comment: @Gimby, the URL without the www. prefix worked for me as well.

Comment: It is with reluctance that I accept this answer.  There is a fundamental problem with discovery for this feature.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Thanks. As I understood, the SE targets mainly the newbies and the first-time users (why they aren't nicer to them, is another topic). This is why is it common, that you need some extra functionality (note, printing is becoming more and more "extra" with time), and you need to search the net a lot for that.