# Can Stack Exchange include a link to StackPrinter for each question directly?

Tags: feature-request, print

**Problem Statement**

The ability to print directly from Stack Overflow and many other Stack Exchange sites is problematic.  Reference: [Have you tried printing an article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381326/have-you-tried-printing-an-article)

The stated solution was to use [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) which is a third party website to fill the need.

The primary problem is that solution is not integrated, so it is easily forgotten.  This will lead to multiple duplicate requests over time.

**Risk**

If StackPrinter goes away, the number 1 answer to "How do I print Stack Overflow questions" is gone.

The only other option is to click the "Mobile" mode button in the footer for a  print solution, which itself would be a reasonable option as a printable view.

**Work Environment**

There are a large number of developers (in the thousands) who have to work in a disconnected environment, and their connection to the internet is typically controlled behind very restrictive firewalls.  The work environment is typically in one of these configurations:

- Dual monitor set up with one monitor connected to the internet and a KVM to switch the other monitor to the network they need to work on.
- Dual monitor set up with both monitors connected to a KVM and the user has to switch between the internet machine and the machine they have to work on.
- "Internet Cafe" where the user has to leave the machines they work on to do their research, print results and carry it in to the work area.

The reasons for the configuration are specific to the organization they work for, but typically has to do with a security posture.  Only the group in the first bullet point can still use StackOverflow without resorting to printing.  Users in the second bullet would have to request a facilities change, which can be denied.

**Request**

As a user in a disconnected environment, I want to reliably print out the Questions and Answers so that I can refer to them when working on a machine without internet access.

The best solution from my standpoint would be:

- Actually fix printing (whether it's CSS or similar to what Google does for printing driving directions)
- Add the link as part of the core website to StackPrinter for the question
- Have a permalink to a page that describes all the alternatives to print an article in one place.

Either solution fixes the fundamental problem of discover-ability when you are under a time crunch.  Stack Overflow is a very important part of development and troubleshooting configuration problems.

Comment: I don't think that stackprinter.com is officially associated with stack overflow so that is most likely not possible.

Comment: I only care that I have a solution that is integrated to print.

Comment: Just use mobile view (you can toggle it at the bottom). That prints sort-of fine, it does leave some irrelevant things such as the answer box but not much.

Comment: @ErikA, that's still a discoverability problem.

Comment: It's an edge-case. For people printing a lot, there are enough workarounds available. Imo we shouldn't encourage printing by making it clearly available in the UI and investing development effort, since I think it benefits very few. But if you want to convince me, start by following the guidance in [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/7296893)

Comment: It honestly feels like this speaks more to a problem with the work environment being restrictive on what sites it allows you and others to access when attempting to diagnose problems more than a lack of a feature on the Stack Exchange network.  Not to be too forceful or too nosy, but a)  how much time have you spent trying to track this problem down, and b) what kind of environment do you work in such that access to Stack Overflow is heavily restricted?

Comment: @ErikA I have reformatted my question which should be more language neutral.  It describes the work environment which is a reality for thousands of developers across the USA.  I can't go into more specifics than what I described.  It took me about an hour to find an answer on how to get printable results.  Under time crunch, that's more time than I wanted to devote to it.

Comment: @Makoto, I elaborated on the work environment which is actually more common than you probably realize.

Comment: Oh I don't disagree there, but if I were a manager I'd probably want less time spent finagling over how to research a problem and more time solving it.  There are contexts around job sites with classified personnel though - [I know that at one point Shog asked about that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344282/1079354) - but I'm still not really seeing this issue as one which isn't solved in another way...

Comment: @Makoto, all I want is to not repeat the nightmare of figuring out how to print all over again.  I think my third alternative is a relatively low cost solution that will at least fit that bill.  Don't you think?

Comment: No, because that gives users the impression that this is a service maintained and provided by Stack Overflow, when it could disappear tomorrow and someone could buy the domain to distribute porn or malware. It also doesn't get *that* much bang for the buck; I can really understand that you're suffering in ways I cannot begin to comprehend, but the vast, vast, *vast* majority of users do not print things from here.  In terms of priority (not to speak for anyone, just thinking out loud if I were a dev there), this would probably fall below things like making search better.

Comment: @Makato. Perhaps, but with your example, that means if StackPrinter suddenly goes away, we've lost the #1 suggested solution for a problem that StackOverflow is not addressing themselves.  That brings us back to the original problem.  If I presented an application to my clients where printing was not an option, I would be required to fix it.  I just don't understand why this has never been prioritized in 10 years (the link provided to me in the original question was from 2009).  That's a lot of time to fix something so small.

Comment: I'm not making any remark on the size of the effort; I'm more remarking on its importance.  In ten or so years, it hasn't risen to the occasion of being something the dev team has focused on.  You're absolutely right - if Stack Printer went dark, then there's nothing which can be done to restore that functionality - but honestly, I'm not seeing a compelling argument to actually focus on it.  I'm no dev here and I don't work here at all, but as an avid consumer of the Stack Exchange network, I would request they focus their energies on something more fruitful than printable questions.

Comment: I'll leave it at this - you're going to likely have an easier time convincing your IT team to either loosen up the restrictions around how you can get information from Stack Overflow, or work on a compromise within your corporation to allow you to do your job more effectively.

Comment: @Makto.  I understand.  I will now begin to boil the ocean.  That is a simpler problem altogether.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I think you've substantially improved your question. I think the chance of it getting implemented is slim because afaik doing it properly (with CSS media selectors so we don't have extra links) is pretty hard, and they've dropped support for working apps to save development effort. But who knows, with Teams and SO getting more business-oriented I wouldn't be that surprised if they addressed this.

Comment: I don't get why this has so many downvotes. It seems like a great idea to me.

Comment: @HFBrowning: that doesn't mean everyone else thinks it is a great idea. Stack Overflow shouldn't implement every single idea out there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess I don't really get meta voting then. Does a downvote mean something shouldn't be implemented? If I saw a feature request on meta that didn't affect me, I would just ignore it rather than downvote, since my experience and use of a website is not indicative of everyone's experience/use. I don't care about Stack Overflow teams, so I'm going to ignore those posts rather than downvote them.

Comment: Anyway, to me the downvotes here are somewhat akin to downvoting a suggestion to make a website screen-readable (for accessibility with JAWS). Just because a situation doesn't affect you doesn't mean it's a stupid idea. A score of 0 would just as forcefully say that an idea doesn't have the support of the community to justify implementation, as a score of -8 does *shrug*

Comment: @HFBrowning That's a common argument for removing downvotes entirely; just move on, don't worry about it, it's fine. That removes the ability to signal that some posts are just not worth your time, or here on Meta, that you disagree with the request. Only allowing apathy or support disregards a critical aspect of feedback.

Comment: @HFBrowning [voting on meta is... different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), especially on feature requests. While some users vote based solely on their usefulness, some extend to thinking about the limited resources of SE devs that would be better allocated in fixing critical bugs & implementing more important feature requests.

Comment: Do you er, have some kind of proof of that "in the thousands" humans working in such an environment?

Comment: Companies like SAIC, Northrop Grunman, Etc. who each have well over 10,000 employees all contribute developers to contracts that operate under those conditions.  My company is just shy of 1,000 employees alone.  1,000s is a very conservative estimate.

Answer (score 5):

You can trivially do this yourself with a userscript (with the TamperMonkey or GreaseMonkey browser extensions) or a bookmarklet.

The StackPrinter website has already created both the script and the bookmarklet. The  [script is available via greasyfork.org](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/12350-stack-overflow-stackprinter), which reportedly adds a printer icon below the vote buttons for you, linking you to the StackPrinter view on the question. I say 'reportedly' because it was recently reported as broken (the Stack Exchange UI changed so it currently can't locate the vote buttons correctly).

There is also a bookmarklet published on StackPrinter, add that to your bookmarks toolbar and it'll also send you to the StackPrinter version of the page currently open in your browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the environments I've described, plugins are disabled (i.e. plugin repositories are blocked) and GreaseMonky is considered inherently unsafe.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch: that's a pity, but is copying and pasting a URL or question ID really so hard? Restricted work setups like you described are just not prevalent enough for this to have to clutter up the UI for everyone else.

Comment: The problem isn't for today.  It's for the next release we need to troubleshoot.  In another month or two I have to rediscover how to print again.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SingleFile](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile) to save important answers to my local hard drive; it is available for both [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/single-file/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle?hl=en). It downloads one HTML file with all the formatting intact! However, it offers convenience at a disadvantage, the file size is substantially larger than the one saved by StackPrinter, for the current question it is around 7.559 times larger. If disk space is not a constraint, it is a very simple solution, being directly accessible from the browser toolbar.

**`SingleFile:`**

[image: SingleFile_save]

**`StackPrinter:`**

[image: StackPrinter_save]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You could just clip the webpage to Evernote using its Web clipper. For example [Evernote version](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s648/sh/f8c21545-596c-424f-8ffc-ee09032f4a08/9faf54c10e3bbb0dd1d6dd1ba31e0d94),  and [actual page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/command-line-tool-for-extracting-searching-and-converting).

> ok I know it is not satisfactory.

I just want you to know that the option exists.